# jQueryUI Resize faster than mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an element, that a user can resize. However due to the constraints of the Iframe it's not easy to resize towards the edges. Once the mouse goes out of the iframe,the event stops.

For a work around I was thinking if there's a way to speed up the resize. Looking through the documentation there's a resize option. Which has a position attribute.
This is what I have tried so far, but it does not work as intended .

```
$("myElement").on("resize", function(e, ui) {
  ui.position.left = ui.position.left * 1.5
})
```

This does not improve the speed in anyway. Am I doing this wrong? Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: is the iframe url on the same server ?

Comment: For now on hosting yes. But the iframe is going to be embedded on the user's website.

Comment: the reason i asked was because you can use jQuery to target elements inside an iframe if its on the same domain. for example: **$("iframe").contents().find("myElement").css("color","#FFF");** - so you could target elements inside the iframe that is on the same domain due to the **same origin policy**